# Disable drop down box on radio button click

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, radio-button

I have two radio buttons and a drop down box as you can see below. What I want to do is:
1. While no is checked, either hide, or grey out the drop down box, and
2. While yes is checked, show the drop down box.

Any pointers would be appreciated!

```
<td colspan="4">
<input name="discount" type="radio" id="Yes" value="Yes" />Yes
<input name="discount" type="radio" id="No" value="No" checked="checked" />No<br />  
<select class="purple" name="discountselection" id="discountselection">
<option value="1 Year" selected="selected">1 Year</option>
<option value="2 Years">2 Years</option>
<option value="3 Years">3 Years</option>
</select>                  
</td>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
                   $("#Yes").click(function() {
                        $("#discountselection").attr("disabled", false);
                        //$("#discountselection").show(); //To Show the dropdown
                    });
                    $("#No").click(function() {
                        $("#discountselection").attr("disabled", true);
                        //$("#discountselection").hide();//To hide the dropdown
                    });
    </script>
```

Also, set the dropdown's display style, or disabled property in HTML based on your default radiobutton selected on page load.

```
 <select  name="discountselection" id="discountselection" disabled="disabled">
    <option value="1 Year" selected="selected">1 Year</option>
    <option value="2 Years">2 Years</option>
    <option value="3 Years">3 Years</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('input:radio[name="discount"]').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val()=='Yes') {
        $('#discountselection').attr('disabled',true);
    } else
        $('#discountselection').removeAttr('disabled');
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uSmVD/

Answer (score 2):

You need to set your `select` control to `disabled` and use a similar code to this one:

```
​$(function(){
    $('input:radio[name=discount]').one('change', function(){
        $('.purple').removeAttr('disabled');
    });
});​
```

See http://www.jsfiddle.net/A3BuQ/6/

Ref.: [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/), [.removeAttr()](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)

Comment: I do have other radio buttons on the page. Will this affect those?

Comment: @TaraWalsh: yes it would. I adapted the code to make it more specific.

Comment: Cool, I have placed this javascript code at the top of my HTML document like so: <script type='text/javascript'>
$(function(){
    $('input:radio[name=discount]').one('change', function(){
        $('.purple').removeAttr('disabled');
    });
});​
</script> Is this the correct way to use this code? Right now it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: This won't re-disable if they change back.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide it with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){     

$('#discountselection').hide();

        $('#No').click(function(){
            $('#discountselection').hide();
        });

        $('#Yes').click(function(){
            $('#discountselection').show();
        });
});
```

check it:
http://www.jsfiddle.net/cFUsU/

UPDATE:  added $(document).ready(); method to start set this code to action when the page is ready

Comment: Hi, where should I insert this javascript? I'm a bit of a newbie to it.

Comment: You can put this inside a `<script type="text/javascript>  //code here </script>` tag inside your `<head> </head>` tags in your HTML

SEE ABOVE: I made a few edits for you

Comment: Yeah I've done that but it doesn't seem to work for me :-\ Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: what does it do?  can I see your code? I'm sure there is something simple missing :)  Did you check it out in jsfiddle?  If you have code I can look at, we'll get it going.

Answer (score 1):

```
​$(function(){
  $('input:radio').bind('change', function(){
     $('#discountselection').attr('disabled', !$("#yes").is(":checked"));
  });
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

Would this do it?

```
$('input:radio').bind('change', function(){
    $('select').attr('disabled', $(this).val() == "No");
});
```

Tested, works great.  Good luck.

Comment: this is trouble. not removing the `disabled` attribute could case some browser to still disable the element, even when it's value is 0. Actually it doesn't matter which value you set, as long as the attribute `disabled` is present, an element must get disabled (w3c).