# dropdownlist selected index option not working with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using an asp.net dropdownlist it contains 5 values the sample code is as follows

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSampledropdown" runat="server" Width="250px">
     <asp:ListItem Value="0" title="--Select--">--Select--</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="1" title="Alpha">Alpha</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="2" title="Bravo">Bravo</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="3" title="Charlie">Charlie</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="4" title="Delta">Delta</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="5" title="Echo">Echo</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

I want to set the dropdownlist as disabled and set the selected text as alpha how can i do this with the help of a javascript in asp.net 2003

I made it as disabled but was unable to set the dropdownlist selected value

Comment: wooow where did you find asp.net 20003? you are about 18.000 years ahead?!

Answer (score 1):

with JQuery, to select Alpha:

```
$("#ddlSampledropdown").val('1');
```

and to disable the control:

```
$("#ddlSampledropdown").attr("disabled", true);
```

sources:

[Change the selected value of a drop-down list with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499405/change-the-selected-value-of-a-drop-down-list-with-jquery)

[Disable drop down box on radio button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701394/disable-drop-down-box-on-radio-button-click)

Comment: Most likely (unless he's on 4.0), his dropdown's id will not be 'ddlSampledropdown'. You might want to change your selector to something like '[id$=ddlSampledropdown]' instead, or use inline script to get the correct ClientId value.

Answer (score 1):

Using classic Javascript, you may consider doing something like this. **Note**: obtain the correct client Id for your drop down.

```
var mydropdown= document.getElementById("ctl00_ctl00_<clientIdForDropdown>");
mydropdown.options[1].selected="selected";
```